# Trying to call Module Sub from Worksheet Sub : 'Run-time Error: 1004'

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing some code in VBA on Excel that follows this process: It searches through column E until it finds the title "Item Name" and then searches through column F until it finds "Sub Total". Based on these two locations, I can sum the total number (n) of values in between them .

This was written in a Module and the code for that is seen below:

```
Public Sub Sum()

Dim Sub_Total As Range
Dim Total As Range

   Set Item_Name = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E:E").Find("Item Name")
   Set Sub_Total = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F:F").Find("Sub Total")

   Range(Sub_Total.Address).Offset(0, 1) = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(Item_Name.Row + 1, 7), Cells(Sub_Total.Row - 1, 7)))

End Sub
```

I then wanted to have a feature that could detect if a user had changed a value within the summing region, and so if a value was changed, it would sum all the values again (run through this sub again).

I wrote that part of the code in Worksheet code and is as follows:

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(Range("E:E").Find("Item Name").Row, 7), Cells(Range("F:F").Find("Sub Total").Row, 7))) Is Nothing Then

        Call Sum

    End If

End Sub
```

I set it so if a user changed a value, then it would call the sub within the module I produced earlier.

However, whenever I try to run this code I get an error that states 'Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error'. When I click Debug it highlights this line of code as the issue:

```
Set Item_Name = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E:E").Find("Item Name")
```

I have tried researching this error and also tried to resolve this issue many times but to no avail. I feel it must be a problem with the calling procedure because the sub Sum() works fine if it isn't called within the Worksheet sub.

Any ideas or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks very much

Comment: You need to test to see if you found anything before you dereference it.

Comment: I'm sorry Comintern, I'm not quite sure what you mean. What should I dereference?

Comment: `.Find("Item Name").Row`.  If the `Find` returns nothing, you'll get an error because you can't call `.Row` on `Nothing`.

Comment: It can find 'Item Name' as I can comment out 'Call Sub' and it runs without any errors. So it seems I can still '.Row'

Comment: I'm not saying that is your specific issue for this question (hence the comment instead of an answer).  I was just pointing out that you need to code defensively so your ***next*** question isn't another run-time error.

Comment: Ah I see Comintern, thank you for your advice.

Comment: You'll probably want to declare `Item_Name` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Mathieu. I was changing the names of things and forgot to change the declaration name. Changed it now. Still the same error unfortunately

Comment: Also not really an answer, but why call a separate sub? Define your two Find variables and then use them in your intersect test and sum range.

Comment: I did try doing it within the intersect sub ie. only having one sub, but I still get the same error message. One thing I have noticed is that when I change a value, Excel does calculate the new sum but once calculated, it the runs the error. Could it be a looping problem?

Comment: I have to say I tried to test your scenario but Excel behaved very strangely and kept freezing. Is your change code in Sheet1's module?

Comment: Yes, my excel also plays up with the code. No idea why. Yeah, theWorksheet_change Sub is in the Sheet1 Module under 'Microsoft Excel Objects'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one kept eating away at me as Excel's behaviour was so strange. This code now works for me (you don't need the other sub).

Turning off events shouldn't be necessary, but does appear to make a difference (and is generally advisable anyway in these circumstances).

You also had `Public Sub Worksheet_Change` which I imagine you typed freehand whereas it should be `Private` (I don't know what difference this makes though).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Sub_Total As Range
Dim Item_Name As Range

Application.EnableEvents = False

Set Item_Name = Range("E:E").Find("Item Name")
Set Sub_Total = Range("F:F").Find("Sub Total")

If Not Item_Name Is Nothing Then
    If Not Sub_Total Is Nothing Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(Item_Name.Row, 7), Cells(Sub_Total.Row, 7))) Is Nothing Then
            Sub_Total.Offset(0, 1) = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(Item_Name.Row + 1, 7), Cells(Sub_Total.Row - 1, 7)))
        End If
    End If
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would modify your code to change your variables to `Long` and add `.Row`
it should work without any problems. I also got rid of the `Offset` because you know what column you want your answer in. You could always declare the two variables as Public and use them in both your macros.

```
Dim Sub_Total As Long
Dim Item_Name As Long

   Item_Name = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E:E").Find("Item Name").Row
   Sub_Total = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F:F").Find("Sub Total").Row

   Cells(Sub_Total, 7).Value = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(Item_Name + 1, 7), Cells(Sub_Total - 1, 7)))
```

Your `Worksheet_Change` could be written like this if you make your variables public...

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(Item_Name, 7), Cells(Sub_Total, 7))) Is Nothing Then
```

Comment: Thanks for the help GMalc. I modified my code to your suggestions but I'm still getting the same error as before unfortunately